# ggplot2: separate color scale per facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

Intuitively I'm looking for something like: `facet_(scales="free_color")`

I do something like

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(year, displ, color=model)) + facet_wrap(~manufacturer)
p + geom_jitter()
```

That is: plot 2d measurements from individuals(`model`) belonging to different species(`manufacturer`) faceted by a species, indicating the individual by color.
The problem is that all individuals share the same color scale - so that the points in a facet have very similar colors.

Using the group aesthetic with geom_line would solve the problem, but lines tell different story than dots.

Another obvious solution would be to drop the faceting and draw a separate plot for each subset. (If this should be the only solution: are there any quick, smart or proven ways to do that?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is an available option when you're colouring by a factor. However, a quick way to produce the individual plots would be something like this:

```
d_ply(mpg, .(manufacturer), function(df) {
jpeg(paste(df$manufacturer[[1]], ".jpeg", sep=""))
plots <- ggplot(df, aes(year, displ, color=factor(model))) + geom_jitter()
print(plots)
dev.off()
})
```

Related Answers: 
[Different legends and fill colours for facetted ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805029)

Comment: As hadley mentioned (in the answer you linked) "it's easy to work around by drawing separate plots" - this shows how. Thanks! But I'm still struggling to combine them in a way that matches the other faceted plots I created.

Comment: Could you show us what you have so far? And try to describe what is/is not matching?

Comment: Actually, perhaps it would be best to ask a new question showing what you currently have in terms of plot(s) and what you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I think you simply want to color by class, where each manufacturer makes several models, each only one or two per class:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(year, displ, color=class)) + facet_wrap(~ manufacturer)
p + geom_jitter()
```

[image]

Comment: The `mpg` dataset was just an example. I want to plot density gradients(`x` vs `y`) of tree(`color` or `group`) samples per species(`facet`). Each individual tree belongs to only one species.