# ggplot2: continuous and discrete scale in facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to create a plot where I show two measures for the same set of points, one with a discrete scale and one with a continuous scale. I want to show the plots side-by-side, and getting them into facets would be great. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to have one color scale in one facet and a different color scale in another.

```r
library(tidyverse)


disc <- tibble(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), color = sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE), model = "discrete")
cont <- tibble(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), color = rnorm(100, 10), model = "continuous")

# want this to be discrete
ggplot(disc, aes(x = x, y = y, color = factor(color))) + 
  geom_point() + scale_color_discrete()
```

[image]

```r
# want this to be continuous
ggplot(cont, aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) + 
  geom_point() + scale_color_viridis_c()
```

[image]

```r
# This would be prettier!
bind_rows( disc, cont ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~model)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I realize that this is probably outside the intended use of facet. But I'm having a harder time getting the maps to print side-by-side in a coherent way and thought this could be a more sustainable shortcut.

[image: side-by-side ggmap]

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805029/different-legends-and-fill-colours-for-facetted-ggplot is similar, but is 11 years old.

Comment: Multiple color scales is not easy in native `ggplot2`, there are packages to support it (`ggnewscale`, `gg4hx`, and `relayer` are three that come to mind). An alternative is to make two completely-different plots and combine them using `patchwork`.

Answer (score 2):

Just learned about `ggnewscale` in my searching, and it seems to be easy enough! :

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)


disc <- tibble(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), color = sample(letters[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE), model = "discrete")
cont <- tibble(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), color = rnorm(100, 10), model = "continuous")

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(data = disc, aes(color = color)) + 
  scale_color_discrete("discrete") + 
  new_scale_color() + 
  geom_point(data = cont, aes(color = color)) + 
  scale_color_viridis_c("continuous") + 
  facet_wrap(~model)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>